# How to query for err in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I added a column to my table **that does not allow null.** I guess that is why some of my rows now have real values in the column but some other rows now have (err) in the column. How can I query for this?

```
select * from Table where new_column = err
```

That doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select * from Table where new_column='err'

Comment: No, that will not work because they are not actual nulls. The column does not allow nulls

Answer (score 0):

`select * from Table where new_column is null`  I think this will work, but my MySQL skills are rusty

Comment: No, that will not work because they are not actual nulls. The column does not allow nulls.